# How can I populate a "user" relation in custom Strapi controller without exposing "find" for all users?

Tags: strapi

I think I'm misunderstanding something fundamental about Strapi: If I want to populate a query in order to obtain all of its relation fields, I need to activate the "find" portion of their APIs. But that then exposes all of that model to everyone....

For example, I have a model called "articles", that has an associated "user" relation. In my custom article.js controller I am trying to allow anyone to see an article, and the corresponding users's name (but only their name). To do this I have something like:

```
async find(ctx) {
    const entries = await strapi.entityService.findMany('api::article.article', {
        populate: {
            user: {fields: ['username']}
        }
    });
    const sanitizedEntries = await this.sanitizeOutput(entries, ctx);
    return this.transformResponse(sanitizedEntries);
}
```

BUT, for this to work I need to enable "find" for the entire user model, which is insecure. Am I missing something obvious with how to achieve this? It seems like a pretty fundamental need in a relational database to allow population without exposing the entire model to everybody.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to implement a middleware as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75447871/3174950).

Short description:

1. Add a strapi-server.js to the user-permissions plugin. (more on that
   topic [here](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/plugins/server-api#middlewares))
2. Add a middleware. (e.g. use `yarn strapi generate`)
3. Implement object sanitization inside your middleware
   e.g.:

```js
// sanitizer function
const sanitizeItem = (item, user) => {
  // check if user is not undefined
  if (user) {
    // check if user id is same as the item.id (user from request)
    if (user.id === item.id) {
      // if it's same return full object
      return item;
    }
  }
  // TODO: rename hiddenField to the field you want to hide
  let { hiddenField, ...rest } = item;
  return rest;
}
```

When trying to hide a users email your middleware could look like that:

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * `user-sanitization` middleware
 */

module.exports = (config, { strapi }) => {
  return async (ctx, next) => {
    // before controller
    await next();
    // after controller
    // we need to check if the reponse is correct, 
    // otherwise we will have error message in the data
    if (ctx.response.status === 200) {
      // get the authenticated user, if no user - undefined
      const { user } = ctx.state;
      // get data from response
      let data = ctx.response.body;
      // check if data is array
      if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        // run sanitize function for each element
        data = data.map(item => sanitizeItem(item, user))
      } else {
        // else run for single item
        data = sanitizeItem(data, user);
      }
      // apply result to response
      ctx.response.body = data;
    }

  };
};

// sanitizer function
const sanitizeItem = (item, user) => {
  // check if user is not undefined
  if (user) {
    // check if user id is same as the item.id (user from request)
    if (user.id === item.id) {
      // if it's same return full object
      return item;
    }
  }
  // else extract email from object
  let { email, ...rest } = item;
  return rest;
}
```