# Private strapi data for current user

Tags: node.js, backend, entity-relationship, strapi

I have order app created on strapi, how can I secure data from other users, but user who create order can view him.

I use relation one-to-many from user to many orders, when `?populate=orders` requests other authorized users can view them, and when I turn off `find` action this field removing from `/users/me?populate=orders`.
How can I set visibility for order by user who made it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would need a middleware for this, the more general approach is to use policy to make users not able to fetch other user data, like here: [Why all users in Strapi have access to update all users profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74728231/why-all-users-in-strapi-have-access-to-update-all-users-profile/74734475#74734475)

So let's mod code a bit to fit your case, the steps we are going to do are following:

- Create global middleware.
- Inject middleware to `user-permissions` routes.
- Mod middleware to remove `orders` from request if user aren't the one that is registered.

The result is if we do `/api/users?populate=orders` or `/api/users/:id?populate=orders` we would not receive orders.

So:

```
strapi generate
```

```
? Strapi Generators middleware
? Middleware name orders
? Where do you want to add this middleware? Add middleware to root of project
```

So by default middleware would log in console:

```
'In orders middleware.'
```

We need to apply it to `find`, `findOne`, `update`, `delete` routes of user-permissions plugin:

`src/extensions/user-permissions/strapi-server.js`

```js
module.exports = (plugin) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < plugin.routes["content-api"].routes.length; i++) {
        const route = plugin.routes["content-api"].routes[i];
        // checks if this one of the routes we target
        if (
            route.handler === "user.findOne" ||
            route.handler === "user.find" ||
            route.handler === "user.update" ||
            route.handler === "user.destroy"
        ) {
            // if it's append middleware to route
            plugin.routes["content-api"].routes[i] = {
                ...route,
                config: {
                    ...route.config,
                    middlewares: route.config.middlewares
                        ? [...route.config.middlewares, "global::orders"]
                        : ["global::orders"],
                },
            };
        }
    }

    return plugin;
};
```

```py
yarn build
yarn develop
```

If you did the step correct you should see:

```py
[2023-02-14 14:59:51.472] http: GET /api/users (30 ms) 200
[2023-02-14 15:00:01.852] info: In orders middleware.
```

every time you hit `/api/users`

Next step we going to tweak middleware, so middleware has two stages, first stage is before `await next()` it's stage that executed before controller, the second stage is after `await next()` is stage executed after controller.

We are going to modify the second stage and if we find attribute `orders` we are going to remove it from response:
`src/middlewares/orders.js`

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * `orders` middleware
 */

module.exports = (config, { strapi }) => {
  return async (ctx, next) => {
    // before controller
    await next();
    // after controller
    // we need to check if the reponse is correct, 
    // otherwise we will have error message in the data
    if (ctx.response.status === 200) {
      // get the authenticated user, if no user - undefined
      const { user } = ctx.state;
      // get data from response
      let data = ctx.response.body;
      // check if data is array
      if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        // run sanitize function for each element
        data = data.map(item => sanitizeItem(item, user))
      } else {
        // else run for single item
        data = sanitizeItem(data, user);
      }
      // apply result to response
      ctx.response.body = data;
    }

  };
};

// sanitizer function
const sanitizeItem = (item, user) => {
  // check if user is not undefined
  if (user) {
    // check if user id is same as the item.id (user from request)
    if (user.id === item.id) {
      // if it's same return full object
      return item;
    }
  }
  // else extract orders from object
  let { orders, ...rest } = item;
  return rest;
}
```

And whoala:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "user1",
        "email": "user1@email.com",
        "provider": "local",
        "confirmed": true,
        "blocked": false,
        "createdAt": "2023-02-14T11:39:43.246Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-02-14T11:39:43.246Z",
        "orders": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Order 1",
                "createdAt": "2023-02-14T11:39:01.990Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-02-14T11:39:01.990Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Order 2",
                "createdAt": "2023-02-14T11:39:09.182Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-02-14T11:39:09.182Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "user2",
        "email": "user2@email.com",
        "provider": "local",
        "confirmed": true,
        "blocked": false,
        "createdAt": "2023-02-14T11:40:04.793Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-02-14T11:40:04.793Z"
    }
]
```

I'm authenticated as user1