# StrapiV4 : how to hide user emails using a middleware?

Tags: middleware, strapi

I'm trying to hide my users emails from the `/users` and `/users/:id` endpoint since it's a security issue.

For instance, here's how I register a middleware for `/users/:id` by editing `src/extensions/user-permissions/strapi-server.js`.

The middleware is located in my custom plugin `spiff`.

```
("use strict");

module.exports = (plugin) => {
  //if you see this, the configuration do loads:
  console.log("Custom strapi-server.js for user-permissions");

  //get api routes for 'user-permissions'
  const apiRoutes = plugin.routes['content-api'].routes;

  //update route GET /users/:id
  apiRoutes
    .filter(route => route.handler === 'user.findOne')
    .map(route => {
      route.config.middlewares = [...(route.config.middlewares || []), 'plugin::spiff.user-find-one'];
      return route;
    });


  return plugin;

};
```

My `user-find-one.js` middleware  :

```
export default (config, { strapi })=> {
  return async (ctx, next) => {
    console.info("running middleware 'user-find-one.js'");
    console.log();

    const controller = strapi.plugin('users-permissions').controller('user');
    await controller.findOne(ctx);//this populates ctx.body
    const data = ctx.body;

    if (data){

      const authUserId = ctx.state.user?.id;//logged user ID
      const isMe = (authUserId === data.id);

      if (!isMe){
        delete data.email;
      }

      ctx.body = data;
    }

    await next();//got a question about this

  }
}
```

I think I have understood that any middleware should end by a call to `await next()` so middlewares are chained (am I right here ?), but that gives me a problem:

- Without `await next()`, my middleware runs and email is removed from the data when calling the endpoint.
- With `await next()`, my middleware runs but email *does* appears in the data when calling the endpoint; as if another function (or middleware) was restoring it.  But I don't see any other middleware registered.

Does someone know if I have to keep that call to `await next()` at the end of my middleware; and how can I understand/debug which function does overrides my output ?

Thanks !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75390415/private-strapi-data-for-current-user/75447871#75447871

Comment: Thanks @antokhio, now I've understood that "middleware has two stages, first stage is before await next() it's stage that executed before controller, the second stage is after await next() is stage executed after controller.".  This was my problem !